# Boss insisting for Bockchain on an existing application

Tags: blockchain

Hello fellow developers,

This is a ...broad question and not much related to coding (but it may lead to coding examples and discussion), please forgive me.

Are you facing this weird problem with your employer : They want you to implement 'blockchain' over an existing software product (in my case a nodejs app) your company developed (while them don't have the least idea what this technology means...because I imagine it requires a whole re-engineering of any existing soft product) , JUST because it's a trendy gimmick now that sounds nice in marketing materials?

Have you ever had a such experience? and how did you deal with it? were you able to remodel it a legacy app to a blockchain app?

Answer (score 0):

Blockchain is a game changer provided it is leveraged for the correct use case.
The first thing to do is to perform fitment analysis to find out Blockchain is right for your business problem.

There are some pointers to do this analysis

1. Does the use case involve multiple parties (preferably across
   organizations)
2. Does the data needs to be distributed and secured
   between multiple parties
3. Does the use case need multiple
   participants to update and share data
4. Does the use case require high
   accountability and transparency between multiple participants

These are some of the questions that need to be answered.

If the analysis reveals that blockchain is indeed the correct solution, then we can start thinking about implementing the business problem using Blockchain. This could involve

1. Complete remodeling from legacy app to blockchain app (or)
2. Building blockchain app that will integrate with the legcy app

2nd Option is probably the most preferred option in many enterprise scenarios